# Swift to create common class for UIButton styles

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am using multiple buttons in multiple class files with same look and feel but action and title is different. So, I need to create common class and all other class needs to refer it for UIButton shadow look.

Also, Please let me know which one is best extension or common class for UIReusability.

Below code I am using

```
sbutton.layer.cornerRadius = 21
sbutton.clipsToBounds = true
sbutton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
sbutton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
sbutton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
sbutton.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
sbutton.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

I'm using Shared Class for this(Write once use every ware)

```
import UIKit
class SharedClass: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SharedClass()

    func styleForComponents(button: UIButton) {
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 21
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        button.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }

    private override init() {

    }

}
```

Call this function like this in entire project

```
SharedClass.sharedInstance.styleForComponents(button: sbutton)
```